# Can I find and replace Core Text/Cocoa text strings in any application?

Tags: applescript, automator, text

My scenario:

- I use an app called [Antetype](http://antetype.com) for UI design.
- Antetype uses OS X-native technologies for text rendering (it uses the system-standard text palette).
- Antetype does not have a find and replace text function.
- I want to find and replace text in an Antetype document.

I am wondering if, because Antetype is using native text, it is possible to use Applescript, Automator, or some other method to find and replace text within an Antetype document.

Comment: What format does Antetype keep its data in?

Comment: As far as I can tell it's just a proprietary blob. I am able to open it in a text editor and find and replace strings there, but saving it after doing so renders the document unusable. Here's a sample document for reference: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3fmgow59mrzg5vw/Text%20test.atype

Comment: It is a SQLlite file and looking at the column names I would guess generated by CoreData

Comment: So, you are looking for a post-processing tool to modify the saved data store rather than a UI scripting tool that would automate any find/replace function while the app is running with the document open?

Comment: How I get there is immaterial to me. Whether I'm modifying the data store or using a script, I just want to change multiple instances of a string in one step.

Comment: Since it is a SQLite document, maybe the easiest thing would be to use find and replace functionality within a SQLite app, if such functionality exists. Of course, something like a script would be better as it would be easier to disseminate and explain to coworkers.

Comment: Unfortunately even when I open it in a SQLite app and locate the appropriate node, the actual text content is stored in a binary, so finding and replacing in that way is not possible. Granted I'm just flailing around so there might be a way.